# All routes causing 404

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess

We are trying to go live with our Laravel project on an Ubuntu server running Apache. While all routes and functionality works locally, after going live, all routes that are not the home route result in a 404 error.

I am using the default laravel .htaccess in the /public directory.

My `/etc/apache2/sites-available` looks as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/public
        <Directory /var/www/mydomain.com/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The `/mydomain.com/` root directory does not currently contain any .htaccess.

I enabled modrewrite using `a2enmod rewrite` and restarted apache after every change.

Has anyone else run into this issue? I appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your document root has `/var/www/html` whereas your directory tag only has `/var/www`. they need to be the same, and perhaps the directory tag needs a `/` after `public'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write `mydomin.com` in every rows. But later you talk about `mydomain.com` folder. (Note the A). Is it just a mistyping?

Update: The problem is an other mistyping: directories should be the same on the following lines:

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/mydomain.com/public>
```

Comment: that was it, `var/www/html` vs `/var/www/`, thank you :D Please edit your solution